# how to deshuffle from shuffle abcd in python?

Tags: python, string, random, shuffle

i write the code to make shuffle and de_shuffle. but in de_shuffle.
this my code:

```
def shuffle_order(plain_text,order):
   return ''.join([plain_text[i] for i in order])


def de_shuffle_order(text_rand,order):
   
   return ''.join([text_rand[i] for i in order],order)

print(shuffle_order('abcd',[2,1,3,0]))
print(de_shuffle_order('cbad',[2,1,3,0]))
```

my output is:

```
 cbda
 abdc #i want to make abcd
```

Comment: your "a" and "d" are misplaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume `'cbad'` is a typo and should be `'cbda'`:

```
def shuffle_order(plain_text,order):
   return ''.join([plain_text[i] for i in order])


def de_shuffle_order(text_rand,order):
    d = dict(zip(text_rand, order))
    return ''.join(sorted(text_rand, key=lambda k: d[k]))


print(shuffle_order('abcd',[2,1,3,0]))
print(de_shuffle_order('cbda',[2,1,3,0]))
```

Prints:

```
cbda
abcd
```